# How to quickly know where an MVC action is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, reference, controller

I am wondering how to know quickly list out all the usages of an action of a controller.
I come from a background of asp.net webform.  With webform it's very easy, just do a find reference or go to the corresponding aspx file to find where a postback event is fired.

but with MVC, an action of a controller can be called from anywhere, maybe even from javascript, visual studio doesn't provide a build-in function to find all references.
Maybe there isn't even a caller. There could be just an action that is not hooked to any caller but only it's view.

e.g. how do I know where is this Save action called? It could be called from any view. It's easier if it's called from other C# actions because Visual studio provides "find all reference " for c# code. but for views , there is such thing.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Save([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromBody] DesignerViewModel formData)
    {}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can browse HttpContext.Current object in your controller. It contains request details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I think you mean how to find the request information during debugging . the problem for me is that I don't even know where to fire up this action. I need to find where the action is called statically before running.